# CLI Curl for Windows 10

Tags: curl, windows-10

The prebuilt versions of [curl.exe for Windows](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), do not work on Windows 10.  When I try to run it, a Windows 10 dialogue pops-up and says:

> This app can't run on your PC.

What are the options for a command-line curl on Windows 10?

Comment: The 64-bit version from [here](http://winampplugins.co.uk/curl/) worked fine for me on Win 10 Pro x64.  This is the `Win64 - Generic` from Darren Owen.

Comment: If PowerShell is an option then you can use `Invoke-WebRequest`, the built-in alias for it is `curl`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx